# Store/ Save boolean values in AsyncStorage in react native

Tags: serialization, react-native, save, boolean, async-await

I need to store boolean values in AsyncStorage in react native application. The value stored will be used in all over the application. Actually, the user will set a variable to true or false in the settings page and based on that value, i make some changes in other pages in the application.

here is the code i'm using
Settings Page (set value to true or false but the default value is true)

```
    constructor(props) {
                super(props);
                this.state ={
                    status: true
                }
            };

      toggleStatus(){
                this.setState({
                    status:!this.state.status
                });

 // AsyncStorage.setItem('myCheckbox',JSON.stringify(this.state.status));

//I even hardcoded the value stored and set it to false but it didn't work 
       AsyncStorage.setItem('myCheckbox',  JSON.stringify(false));
                    }
        .. 
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.toggleStatus.bind(this)}>
            <Text> touch me </Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
```

and in one of the other pages where I'll be using that value stored in the  AsyncStorage:

```
componentDidMount() {

        const value =   AsyncStorage.getItem('myCheckbox', (value) => {
            JSON.parse(value)
            console.log("my check box value ", value)
        });
```

But I keep getting this in the console : [image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the React Native docs for AsyncStorage ([here](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/asyncstorage.html)), it says that all methods return a `Promise`.

You can either use `async/await` but we'll do it the `ES6` way.

```
AsyncStorage.getItem('myCheckbox').then((value) => {
 console.log(value);
});
```